# Positioning elements along the visible border of a parent div

Tags: css

I've not been able to find anything on this topic, oddly; I figured it'd be a pretty common issue!

What I've got is a parent div with a `border-radius` to make the div circular. Nested in that div, I've got several child divs that I would like:

- Positioned directly on the visible circular borders (as opposed to the invisible square "border" that surrounds the div -- [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/) hopefully will clarify what I'm trying to say here).
- In addition, I'd like to be able to precisely position the child divs along different points of this border (so, something like "position childDiv1 at the 90deg position [or the 105deg position, 120deg, 135deg, etc.] of the circular parent div" instead of having to use `top` and `left` or assign absolute pixel values or something).

Still an amateur trying to figure out CSS positioning, so I'm not even sure if any of this is possible, haha. Looking forward to any input you guys can provide!

Comment: Do the children divs need to be pixel width or can they be % ? I think I can make this, but percentages would be simpler.

Comment: If all your `DIV`s are in fixed scale, you can still calculate the position (by hand or by javascript)... e.g. Your parent `DIV` in fiddle is a 150 radius circle, and child `DIV` is 30 length squares, so a 90deg child `DIV` (count by the center point) can be: left (150-15)px, top (150-sqrt(150^2-15^2))px.

Comment: I think you'll have to calculate it, http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/9/

Comment: >iight - The child divs can be percentage-width if need be!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use css3 [transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property) and [transform-origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-origin-property) to achieve this

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child1"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child2"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child3"></div>
    <div class="child" id="child4"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    border-radius: 150px;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #666;
    left: 135px;
}
#child1{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin:50% 150px;
}
#child2{
    transform: rotate(105deg);
    transform-origin:50% 150px;
}
#child3{
    transform: rotate(120deg);
    transform-origin:50% 150px;
}
#child4{
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform-origin:50% 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/20/

Comment: This is actually exactly what I'm looking for!! Obviously I'll have to craft some sort of IE 6-8 workaround, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a bunch; this'll be super useful. :D

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/15/
(updated to show that `top:0` does not protrude the circle.)

Or http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/17/, which just looks a lot cooler :}

**EDIT**: I think I misunderstood your question. I will update or delete my answer depending on...my answer.

Comment: By using `top:0` and things like that, _in theory_ your squares would stick out of the circle......

Comment: Please see my updated jsfiddle link...But If this doesn't work, then in theory, he will need to use `overflow:hidden` on the bigger circle, or not use squares for the children divs

Comment: It looks like regardless of what I try to do, the positions are still gonna have to be manually discovered and set, yes? (So, instead of saying "go to position 90deg", I've gotta say "go to `top: 44%; right: 0;`")

With that in mind, though, this particular setup looks great, and I think I'll just have to sit down and work out the exact percentage positioning for each of my divs. :P Thanks for this!!

Comment: er, I only just noticed that there are other answers below this one, and one of them actually provided exactly what I was searching for. iight's answer still provides some excellent insight, though! Thanks, iight!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zSdsg/14/

would something like this be what your looking for?

```
#parent {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px dotted #000;
border-radius: 150px;
}

#child {
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background-color: #666;
}
#child2 {
position: absolute;
top:35px;
left:40px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
    border-radius: 150px;
}
```

​

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
<div id="child2"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Mm, yeah, sorta, though the goal is to not have to manually discover and set all of the position values I need (as absolute pixel values, percentages, etc.), but rather just direct the div to a specific point along the circumference of the parent div.

Comment: ah, got it, not sure myself, but that is a great question.  I suppose now to take it a step further, the idea would be to dynamically add the "locations" to create motion with JavaScript...